# how to retrieve google user's profile information using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: .net

Below are the code I have used:

```
// Retrieve the user's profile information
MessageReceivingEndpoint GetProfileEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://apps- apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
var request = google.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(GetProfileEndpoint, accessToken);
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

From the above code I got bad request error. Any pointer to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your URL with the space?
https://apps-SPACE-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly
Should be:
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly